# VS: Tooltip help for doxygen-style commented functions?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, documentation, doxygen

I am using Visual Studio and an external library that is commented in doxygen-style. Is there any way to display doxygen documentation in the editor tooltip like DocXML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The VS plugin *Visual Assist* shows doxygen comments. From what I can see, it doesn't actually *process* them, but it shows doxygen comments (in their raw form) nevertheless.
There's a trial at their [website](http://www.wholetomato.com/).
Be warned, though. I have seen very few C++ programmers who tried it for a few days and were *not* begging their managers to buy it for them afterwards.

Comment: Thanks, that's currently the nearest thing to a solution. I hope someone make an addin for doxygen comments. For now, I'll have to read the source.

Comment: Sorry for necroposting, but can you please give some references or instructions on how to show doxygen comments using Visual Assist?

Comment: @Alexey: I haven't written C++ in VS for many years, and I do not know how this works nowadays. Sorry, but I can't help you there. `:(`

Answer (score -1):

Not that I am aware of (though I'd love to hear if there is a solution, as doxygen format is much more readable than XML).

A "workaround" I can suggest is that my [AtomineerUtils](http://www.atomineerutils.com/) add-in can bulk-convert Doxygen format comments into DocXML, which is then picked up and used for Intellisense tooltips. (And Doxygen is able to read DocXml, so you keep most of that functionality too). Currently the conversion is a fairly simple one, but I'm working on some improvements at the moment that should make it much more flexible with respect to input comment formats.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't do that. The library is not in my control :(

PS: why can I post comments, but not vote?

Comment: @Hoihoi: Read the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq.

Comment: I keep running into your self-promotions all over stack overflow. I'm tempted, but it's way too expensive. Especially considering it's listed in USD, and that means it's like twice as expensive for me.